# Unable to add more than one read_json method to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two files from which i am trying to write each into a dataframe. However, when i add more than one read_json method in my code, I get the following errror:

```
File "/Users/pmall/Desktop/Python Pratice/hello.py", line 29, in <module>
  df=pd.read_json('/Users/pmall/Desktop/Python Pratice/test2.json')

File "/Users/pmall/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py", line 427, in read_json
  result = json_reader.read()

File "/Users/pmall/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py", line 537, in read
  obj = self._get_object_parser(self.data)

File "/Users/pmall/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py", line 556, in _get_object_parser
  obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()

File "/Users/pmall/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py", line 652, in parse
  self._parse_no_numpy()

File "/Users/pmall/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py", line 871, in _parse_no_numpy
  loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None)

ValueError: Expected object or value
```

The code I am trying is as following :

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_json('/Users/pmall/Desktop/Python Pratice/test1.json')
df2=pd.read_json('/Users/pmall/Desktop/Python Pratice/test2.json')
```

Why am I unable to add more than one read_json?

Comment: Are the two jsons the same? can you provide a sample of your json?

Comment: The two JSONs are same structurally. The value data is different but the keys  contained are the same.